# Large submit->start delay in OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl

I'm seeing massive delays between a kernel being submitted to an AMD GPU and actually executed. My program is doing blocking writes/reads (with blocking=CL_TRUE) to ensure that I/O isn't interfering with the kernel. I then use clGetEventProfilingInfo to get info on kernel queueing, submitting, starting and ending. The data (and code) below shows that the kernel spends about 5 seconds submitted, and then 5 seconds running. In general, it looks like the submitted time scales with the running time. I've looked at a number of forum posts about delays in kernel execution (for instance, http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/166587) but there doesn't seem to be a resolution there. I've checked that the GPU is not in low-power mode. Has anyone else seen this or have suggestions of how to diagnose it?

```
write 131.000000 ms
kernel queued->submitted 0.022348 ms
kernel submitted->started 5553.957663 ms
kernel started->ended 5529.893060 ms
read 39.000000 ms

1306       cl_ulong end, queued, start, submit;
1307       clGetEventProfilingInfo(jniContext->exec_event,
1308               CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(queued), &queued, NULL);
1309       clGetEventProfilingInfo(jniContext->exec_event,
1310               CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT, sizeof(submit), &submit, NULL);
1311       clGetEventProfilingInfo(jniContext->exec_event,
1312               CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(start), &start, NULL);
1313       clGetEventProfilingInfo(jniContext->exec_event,
1314               CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(end), &end, NULL);
```

Comment: Could you add the code you use to measure? The full code I mean, wwhen you launch the kernels, etc.

Comment: Sure, the full code is available at: http://pastebin.com/SCpcRrjP

Comment: I see you are only running one kernel one time. You will often see large timing results on the first invocation of a kernel. Many OpenCL implementation defer certain operations until the last moment, and this work might cause the first run to take longer than subsequent runs. To benchmark a kernel you may need to run it a number of times. Some call this "warming up the GPU."

Comment: @dithermaster yes, soon after posting that code I added a loop around the kernel but found that made no difference. However, I just upgraded to the latest beta amd driver and that fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up: after upgrading from the latest release drivers (v13.4 released on 5/29/2013) to the latest beta drivers (release 11/22/2013) we're no longer seeing this performance issue. This problem occurred on 64-bit Centos using a AMD A10-6700, but if you're seeing this issue and have a different chipset I'd recommend upgrading to the latest beta drivers and seeing if that fixes it.